# asigning values to textbox from jquery slider

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-slider

how do I assign the minimum and maximum value of the slider to the textbox1 and textbox2 respectively? Also, I only know javascript and haven't used this before.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
 $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
   range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 500,
  values: [ 75, 300 ],
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  }
 });
 $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
   " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
 } );
</script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <p>
 <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
 <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
 </p>

  <div id="slider-range"></div>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox 
  ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What do you need the textboxes for? The min and max of your slider are already shown in the "amount" input. Do you need them to send to your backend?

Comment: @AsheraH yes, I need these values to run through database.